# Cannot display switch in tabs in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need my tabs to have a tab consisting of a switch but when I implemented it as it was said, I am not able to see it there.
Maybe it's hidden underneath but I tried changing its z-index.

[image: Edit rough-bird-noszl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your `Switch` component as the `label` prop.

```js
...
<Tab
  component="span"
  label={
    <Switch
      checked={isSwitchOn}
      onChange={(e) => setSwitch(!isSwitchOn)}
      name="toggleType"
    />
  }
/>
```

[image: Edit fervent-swanson-1257k]

Answer (score 1):

`Tab` component does not display `children` props inside the `MuiTab-wrapper` element.

Maybe you can use `icon` props.

```
<Tab
  component="span"
  icon={
    <Switch
      checked={isSwitchOn}
      onChange={(e) => setSwitch(!isSwitchOn)}
      name="toggleType"
    />
  }
/>
```